# Changing image node to another corner

Tags: java, awt

So basically i decided to start a small project but i noticed the node of the image is at the upper left corner. So for example, the x and y values are from that corner. I'd like them to be starting at the bottom left corner. How can i change that?

Sorry if node isn't the right name.

Comment: x, y+height if he wants them in the bottom left corner. But the question isn't really clear to me, can you post some code of what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java `Component` uses the **top left** as the origin of the axis. So if you it to be at the bottom left, you need to add the height of the component to the `y` coordonate.
You should set the location to `x, y+ component.getHeight()`